# JPA: why were the join tables not created?

Tags: java, database, jpa, glassfish

In my application, I have the following `Student` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Student extends Commenter implements Serializable {
    ...
    @OneToMany
    private List<Coupon>   coupons;
    @OneToMany
    private List<Receipt>  receipts;
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Course>   courses;
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Sessions> sessions;
    ...
}
```

When I deploy the app locally, everything works fine. However, when I deployed the app on our server, the join tables `student_coupon` and `student_receipt` were not created.

I tried to drop the whole database and re-create all tables but I have no idea why the above 2 tables were never created. The other join tables (`student_sessions` and `student_course`) are always created correctly though.

I'd be very grateful if you could give me an advice.

Best regards,

Comment: Did you check if you have a join column in your coupons, receipts, courses and sessions tables? As far as I can remember, if you have bidirectional OneToMany relationships they'll use join columns.

Comment: @Gamb: :) my relationships are unidirectional. Besides, as I mentioned in my post, the table were created when I deploy my app locally.

Comment: Just curious: what DB are you using locally and what is remote? Sometimes I have hit snags where my local H2/Derby was fine with a table name and the remote SQL Server/MySQL didn't like it.

Comment: @jwj: I am using MySQL on both machines :).

Comment: Just a shot in the dark but are the versions of MySQL/Glassfish on both machines the same?

Comment: @siebz0r: my local MySQL is 5.5 while the online MySQL is 5.0.77. I don't think it's the reason though

Comment: @Mr.J4mes please post your persistence.xml

Answer (score 1):

For what you say I'm guessing that you have a many to many relationship with the other two Entity (Coupon and Receipt), But you marked them as "One To Many" relationships so there was never going to be a join table, so you must annotate the relationship fields with the @ManyToMany annotation instead (like you have done with the other two fields):

```
@Entity
public class Student extends Commenter implements Serializable {
    @ManyToMany  //Changed this
    @JoinTable(name = "student_coupon",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="studentId")},     //This could be omitted 
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="couponId")} //and left defaults
    private List<Coupon>   coupons;
    @ManyToMany //and this
    @JoinTable(name = "student_receipt",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="studentId")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="receiptId")}
    private List<Receipt>  receipts;
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Course>   courses;
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Sessions> sessions;
}
```